# SQLite locking errors between Obj-C and Javascript

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have an

**iOS**

application which is employing a small trick/hack to communicate between **Objective-C** and Javascript inside a `UIWebView`.

A `SQLite` database and schema is created on startup using the [Javascript DB interface for Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH3-SW1).

When the app is running, every second, the `Obj-C` code reads data from a circuit board and *writes* the data to the same `SQLite` database.  Also every second, the Javascript will *read* from the database and execute some javascript to update the `UIWebView`.  So, there is not much load on the **DB** file.

Every now and then, I'll get **DB** locked errors when trying to write into the **DB** (I'm using [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to execute all sql):

```
2014-07-23 23:00:10.328 RLog[716:60b] Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu 
2014-07-23 23:00:10.328 RLog[716:60b] DB Query: INSERT INTO DEMO2 (time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
2014-07-23 23:00:10.329 RLog[716:60b] Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (5: database is locked)
2014-07-23 23:00:10.329 RLog[716:60b] DB Query: INSERT INTO DEMO2 (time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2014-07-23 23:00:10.329 RLog[716:60b] RLog: err code: 5, database is locked
```

The table is very basic and the insert code is equally as basic where I'm just inserting some floating point values:

```c
NSString *insertSql = @"INSERT INTO DEMO2 (time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr) VALUES (%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f)";

BOOL inTransaction = [_fmdb beginDeferredTransaction];
if ( ! inTransaction ) {
    NSLog(@"RLog: err code: %d, %@", [_fmdb lastErrorCode], [_fmdb lastErrorMessage]);
}

BOOL success = [_fmdb executeUpdateWithFormat:insertSql, time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr];
if ( ! success ) {
    NSLog(@"RLog: err code: %d, %@", [_fmdb lastErrorCode], [_fmdb lastErrorMessage]);
}
[_fmdb commit];
```

Strangely enough, this seems to happen fairly regularly when I execute some other actions which read from a completely separate SQLite file which is only being accessed from the `Obj-C` code (not use for communication bridge between `Obj-C` and JS).

I can't figure out why or how the DB would become locked with such a small number of reads and writes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any chance of these timers being called from separate threads or running concurrently, then all you might need to do is use a `FMDatabaseQueue` instead of the db directly, i.e.:

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#using-fmdatabasequeue-and-thread-safety

For example, hanging onto it as a peer of _fmdb:

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:aPath];
self.fmdbQueue = queue;
```

Then later on:

```
[_fmdbQueue inDeferredTransaction:(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {
    // read data from the db
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from foo"];
    while ([rs next]) {
        …
    }

    // write data out
    NSString *insertSql = @"INSERT INTO DEMO2 (time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr) VALUES "
    "(%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f)";

    BOOL success = [_fmdb executeUpdateWithFormat:insertSql, time, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, hr];
    if ( ! success ) {
        NSLog(@"RLog: err code: %d, %@", [_fmdb lastErrorCode], [_fmdb lastErrorMessage]);
        *rollback = YES;
        return;
    }
 }]; // commit will be executed automatically for us if we didn't flip the value of *rollback.
```

That way all the reads/writes will happen in order removing any possibility of two trying to run at the same time.

*NOTE:* This assumes that the UIWebView (Javascript) is not opening/locking it. If it is, then I'm not sure how you could protect it unless you moved the creation of the db out of javascript (i.e., all inside Objective C)